# responsive menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

Going through some tutorials for bootstrap. Did everything as is told in the video, but still,  i don't get that responsive effect with a button.
Tutorial is here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2tOSnnlyiw&list=PLKlA1QwYBcmcEUUBSmkl8_kgwn-_zuy-W
My code

```
 <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a href="#" class="brand"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICS <a class="caret"></a></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What am I missing? One of the options would be to make it fluid, but i still want to learn making it work with the button.

Comment: Seen lots of tuts on tb, most of which are out of date.  Best thing to do is get the latest version and copy the docs [found here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this URL. I hope it will solve your problem - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.